# What is difference between Model of MVC ,data and data base?

Tags: model-view-controller, web, web-applications

I am really confused with the Model of MVC architecture and data. I know database is stored data. Please answer following question
Q1) In the following code please tell me that is Model and what is view?
Q2) When data/database become Model?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Is this line is a model or a view or data?</p>

<p>In my opinion this button is a controller that shows 
"Hello world" as a view. Am i right?</p> <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please explain in context of web application.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is an architectural pattern.

In a short sense:

- Model handles the data
- View displays the data through charts, graphs, text, etc.
- Controller links M and V

Q1) In the following code please tell me that is Model and what is view?

The code you have is a view.

Q2) When data/database become Model?

Data does not become a model per se. Instead, it becomes an instance of a model. When you execute a query and store it to an object, the query results become the contents of the model object.